# (DOORS/DXL) Get highlighted/selected objects?

Tags: ibm-doors

Is it possible to use dxl to obtain the currently selected objects?

thanks Jaambageek for all your help

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14591338

Comment: Yep thats the way I would have gone with.